# How do I know my model overfits?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting, bias-variance-tradeoff

We already have multiple questions on [overfitting](/questions/tagged/overfitting), however, we also observe certain kinds of questions to re-occur regularly that ask how to diagnose overfitting in practice. Let's try giving an authoritative answer for such a question, so it could serve as a reference.

*How do I know my model overfits?* For example: does perfect training error mean overfitting, or how big does the gap between training and test error need to be to call it overfitting?

Comment: I think that your question needs a bit more context for the concept of "overfitting" to be properly defined. I think "overfitting" is only a useful concept when prediction is the ultimate aim of the model fitting (as is usually the case in machine learning).

Comment: @GordonSmyth what other understanding would you considet? The term seems to be well-established and rather self-explanatory.

Comment: @GordonSmyth I think overfitting is also quite relevant when inference is the ultimate aim.

Comment: This post strikes me as overly broad and unfocused for our format.  One way to achieve your aims would be to identify existing threads that already answer your (three separate) questions and curate them.

Comment: @Tim Your question assumes the existence, or at least relevance, of training and test datasets, which implicitly implies a prediction or classification purpose. I was trying to prompt you to make the implicit assumptions of your question more explicit. One can't give authorative answers to incompletely specified questions.

Comment: @whuber there is only one question, edited for clarity.

Comment: @GordonSmyth I don’t assume train/test split, this was just an example (edited). I mean in here the overfitting in machine learning sense (added a tag to make it more clear).

Answer (score 2):

Re last question: There is no fixed threshold. "Overfitting" is not a binary concept. Particularly, some people will use the term if the test error is any larger than what should be expected from the training error (a certain difference is almost always to be expected), some others may not call a model overfitted that has a substantially larger test error than the training error, as long as the test error is still better than what they get from alternative models. I'd say both are legitimate, and people should say more precisely what they mean. Another issue is that a test error that is achieved on random parts of the same data may still be optimistic when it comes to predicting proper new data.

Answer (score 2):

While this question is prone to soliciting "takes" rather than answers, here's mine:

You don't.

Assuming you have used all available resources (i.e. data), regardless of the methodology applied, you don't know if your model is overfit or not. Conversely, modeling techniques that are prone to bias and overfitting may be accurate after all. During independent review, models built using poor methods are dismissed because those methods have poor operating characteristics, but even the crappy archer hits the occasional bullseye. All this is true inspite of any pre-specified objectives, or knowledge of what "plausible" or "good" models might look like apriori. For instance, before the BRCA gene was identified, we had a somewhat pessimistic view of how accurate breast cancer risk models could be, and nothing could have anticipated how powerful their prognostic value might be based on previously researched risk factors.

Comment: I'm still puzzled why "You don't". According to definition of overfitting on wiki it's "the production of an analysis that corresponds too closely or exactly to a particular set of data, and may therefore fail to fit additional data or predict future observations reliably", meaning it should be easy to observe overfitting on a new data (i.e. model doesn't generalize well) and come to a conclusion about overfitting.

Comment: Somehow you read the wiki and miss the exact same point in my answer. Yes, you need to apply a prediction model in a new scenario hence new data -- in fact, it needs applied in multiple new scenarios -- to get a realistic idea of how it works. In practice, you don't have that new data. And no, splitting a sample up randomly isn't what we mean by "new data".

Comment: I don't think it's true. It might be true for simple cases of predicting coordinates of next point in 2d space - whatever model outputs becomes truth in the absence of new data. But let's take recent example of [Rembrandts art restoration](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/commentisfree/2021/jul/03/enjoy-the-restored-night-watch-but-dont-ignore-the-machine-behind-the-rembrandt), the artist passed away long time ago (no new data), but it's still possible to tell if the result of restoration is similar to original artist's style or isn't (observe overfitting).